# Scikit-learn 1.2.0 extremely slow in VScode

Tags: python, machine-learning, visual-studio-code, scikit-learn, pylance

Trying the last couple days to find the causing problem of a testing python file. After many tries and research I didn't find any solution. There is no problem with the extensions, I disabled every single extension and running extension except from Pylance and Python.

At the beginning, I thought it would be problem with the python version 3.10.7 but then I installed the 3.10.9 version and I had the same issue again and again. An other idea was to downgrade VScode, Pylance and Python extension version or run it in Linux and in my brothers computer, but it didn't help either.

I tested out all the installed modules and it happens only with scikit-learn. From the  `Python: Show Language Server Output` takes around 6s for checking and analyzing a simple module assignment like `metrics.`. Is `scikit-learn` a complicated module and takes more time to read the source code?

It takes a lot of time for loading `metrics.` and it's very annoying.
I tried this.

```
from sklearn import metrics
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y_true = ["cat", "ant", "cat", "cat", "ant", "bird"]
y_pred = ["ant", "ant", "cat", "cat", "ant", "cat"]


conf_matrix = metrics.confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels=["ant", "bird", "cat"])

conf_display = metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay(conf_matrix, display_labels=["ant", "bird", "cat"])

accuracy = metrics.accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred, normalize=True)

print(accuracy)

conf_display.plot()

plt.show()
```

Comment: pls share operating system(linux?) and also how you are executing the file ? when i used vscode and then ran the python file `python3 slow_sklearn.py` it was fast. you can also try running this file from the terminal/command line, does it slow there too ?

Comment: I am using linux Mint 21 Cinnamon distribution  through virtual box, I don't have any problem by running the file, but I suppose with the IntelliSense and autocomplete it takes a lot of time to analyze the file from 6 to 8 seconds. This problem is only in `sklearn` , when I am typing i.e. `metrics.` takes a long time for the IntelliSense to analyze the file with long operations.

Comment: I think this problem is difficult to reproduce. On my machine, I use `metrics.`, it took about three seconds to wait and then jump out of the list. When I use it again or reload vscode, it can respond immediately.

Comment: You could submit this problem to developer in [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues).

Comment: I did it already in github they don't have any idea. I moved now in PyCharm, but this is nightmare they have a lot of bugs problems. For me in VScode is the best solution.